# How to define an array in twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to display an image in `twig` based on a value that comes from controller. For example there in an image of a home that should appear if the value coming from the controller is (Home or home or renovation or Renovation or rent or Rent) and the list goes on.

At the moment what is am doing is as following

```
{% if goal == "house" or  goals == "House" or goal == "home" or  goals == "Home" %}
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/bundlename/images/house.jpg') }}">
{% endif %}
```

The list is pretty long and this is soon going to get out of hand. So I was thinking to simply create an array in twig and check if the value coming from controller exist on that array i have in twig to display an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define an array with `{key: value}` or `[value1, value2]` syntaxes. Read more about arrays and twig itself [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#literals).

You can do something like:

```
{% set images = {
    "house.jpg": ["house", "House", "home", "Home"]

    ... some more rules ...

} %}

{% for image, keys in images %}
    {% if goal in keys %}
        <img src="{{ asset('bundles/bundlename/images/' ~ image) }}">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also you can simplify your code to `{% if goal|lower in keys %}` and define keys only in lower case if you always have to check to both cases.

Comment: I think this is a good solution. I also recommend to add assetic image path definition in `config.yml`, so you can manage assets in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an Array in twig

```
{% set section = { foo:{ heading:"bar" } } %}

{{ section.foo.heading }}

bar //output



{% set section = { foo:"bar" } } %}

{{ section.foo }}

bar //output


{% set section = { foo:"bar", one:"two" } } %}

{{ section.one }}

two //output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set array = { 0:"gleneagles-experience", 1:"why-choose", 2:"partners", 3:"plan-travel", 4:"hospital-stay", 5:"going-home", 6:"helpful-resources" } %}
```

**is equivalent to below array in php---**

```
$array  = ["gleneagles-experience","why-choose","partners","plan-travel", "hospital-stay","going-home","helpful-resources"];
```